# my girl says " I miss you". i would like to know real meaning of it?

Tags: grammar

I met my girl friend a few days ago. She told me that " I missed you". So I would like to know real meaning of it. please explain me. thanks for your effort guys for spending me.

Comment: Have you noticed any nearby gunshots?  (Note that "I miss you" and "I missed you" are two quite different statements.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about reading the mind of a girl we don't know.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "I miss you" and "I missed you" are two entirely different things, and it's not clear which you're talking about.

Comment: @HotLicks They're different tenses, but apart from that they mean the same thing in the sense of having felt someone's absence. There doesn't seem to be much doubt that's the sense he's talking about—the trouble is that he wants to know what his girlfriend **really means** when she tells him she's missed him. That's a job for a couples counsellor or a mind reader, not a website.

Comment: Have you tried asking her? I recommend against dating anyone with whom you can't openly discuss your feelings.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - No, you are wrong.  They MIGHT mean the same thing, depending on context, or they could be completely different.

Comment: @HotLicks How so, exactly? “I miss you when you're gone” and “I missed you when you were gone” mean the same thing apart from tenses; the same goes for “I miss you whenever I try to shoot you” and “I missed you whenever I tried to shoot you”. The difference in tenses has no different or additional significance than it does elsewhere.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - "I missed you at the concert."

Comment: @HotLicks “I miss you at every concert I go to”. Again, tense itself isn't the main factor—it's the entire context that determines the meaning of the verb, not its tense. “I miss you” and “I missed you” **can** mean different things in different contexts, but so can “I miss you” and “I miss you”.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning depends on the context. If your girlfriend likes you, then she'd rather be with you, and when she says "I missed you", then it's likely she means something like

> I noticed that you were absent, and I'm feeling lonely without you.

If you were supposed to be at a work meeting, you forgot to go, and your boss says "I missed you", then it's likely she means something like

> I looked for you at the meeting, I expected to find you, but you were absent, and I'm not happy about that.

If you're in a class in which the teacher has just handed out copies of her lecture notes, you point out that she didn't give you a copy, and she says "I missed you", then it's likely that she means

> I'm sorry, I overlooked you.

The verb *to miss* also means to fail to hit a target. Thus HotLick's little joke that if you've heard a gunshot, you turn to see your girlfriend holding a gun, and she says "I missed you", then she likely means

> I fired a gun at you, but I didn't hit you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different meanings of the word miss.

The Oxford on-line [dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/miss) gives the following (as meaning 3.1(

> Feel regret or sadness at no longer being able to enjoy the presence of.

So when you saw her, and she told you that she missed you, she probably meant that during the time when you were not with each other she felt sad. She gets sad when you are not there.

Another possible meaning of miss is to fail when trying to hit somebody, so she may have attempted to throw something at you and it did not hit you.

Most likely, she feels sad when you are not there.

Comment: But if she said "I missed you" (as the OP states) then that likely just means she didn't see you in class or some such.